# How to retrieve data with htaccess Rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**please help, how do I retrieve data "page" from the following url:**

mysite/start/search/indonesia/bali/18Jul2014/19Jul2014/100?page=2

**if i use htaccess to direct?**

This part of the line my htaccess

```
RewriteRule start/search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?pg=(.*)$ printdata.php?data=$1+$2+$3+$4+$5+$6 [QSA,L]
```

please help .. thank you response correction.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{THE_REQUEST}` variables. The query string (everything after the `?`) isn't part of the URI that you match against in rewrite rules.

So:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+start/search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\?pg=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /printdata.php?data=%1+%2+%3+%4+%5+%6 [QSA,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pg=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^start/search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /printdata.php?data=$1+$2+$3+$4+$5+%1 [QSA,L]
```